# Passing optional arguments to asyncpg

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, asyncpg

I am writing a Python function to be a wrapper around PostgreSQL calls I make frequently in my Discord bot. One of these calls is to update the guild settings table, however, the arguments (except for the guild ID) are all effectively optional -- I don't want to pass them if I'm not updating that element. The table structure is created with the following PostgreSQL snippet:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS guild_config (
    guild_id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    prefix VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '>',
    guild_owner BIGINT NOT NULL,
    guild_admin BIGINT[] NOT NULL DEFAULT [0],
    guild_mod BIGINT[] NOT NULL DEFAULT [0],
    guild_super BIGINT[] NOT NULL DEFAULT [0],
    guild_request_roles BIGINT[] NOT NULL DEFAULT [0],
    guild_timezone VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'America/Los_Angeles'
);
```

The python function signature is as follows:

```py
async def guild_set(
        self,
        guild_id: int,
        prefix: Optional[str] = None,
        owner: Optional[int] = None,
        admins: Optional[List[int]] = None,
        mods: Optional[List[int]] = None,
        supers: Optional[List[int]] = None,
        request_roles: Optional[List[int]] = None,
        timezone: Optional[str] = None,
    ) -> None:
```

How can I call asyncpg.connection.execute() to properly place the optional arguments in the row? I can do:

```py
        async with self.pool.acquire() as conn:
            await conn.execute(
                "INSERT INTO guild_table "
                "(guild_id, prefix, guild_owner, guild_admin, guild_mod, guild_super, guild_request_roles, guild_timezone) VALUES "
                "($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) ON CONFLICT (guild_id) DO UPDATE SET prefix = $2, guild_owner = $3, "
                "guild_admin = $4, guild_mod = $5, guild_super = $6, guild_request_roles = $7, guild_timezone = $8",
                guild_id,
                prefix,
                owner,
                admins,
                mods,
                supers,
                request_roles,
                timezone,
            )
```

to update the entire table, but let's say I do not pass an argument for `supers`. How can I make the SQL query here dynamic and work around the missing argument? Is there an asyncpg method to do this?

EDIT: To clarify, this is on an `UPDATE` query, not an `INSERT` query. I am aware that I marked it with `NOT NULL`, so I would have to insert on the first go-round, but this question is about what would happen if I wanted to update a pre-existing record.

Comment: as you didn't allow NULL for supers, you need to add it.

Comment: @nbk, Right, yes, if I was doing an initial insert, but the question is if I already have data in the table. I'll edit to try to clarify as much as possible.

Comment: The update has too be constructed, you can add to the string all columns that should be updated, or you update all columns and enter "the old" values as well as te new ones, but usually you update one a few values and so the programming is quickly done